# Chrome driver 113 not support existing chrome browser version 120.0.6099.130

Tags: jmeter

When I ran jmeter - selenium web driver script while launching the browser getting below error

Org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: session not created

This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 113

Current browser version is 120.0.6099.130 with binary path C:\program Files(x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\Chrome.exe

Please help me to over come thei issue

Comment: Why not use a Chromedriver version that matches the Chrome version, or a Chrome version that matches the driver's version?

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/ page, locate the ChromeDriver version which **exactly matches** your Chrome browser version and replace the ChromeDriver binary with this new one.

Going forward you can use [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) with [WebDriverManager](https://bonigarcia.dev/webdrivermanager/) somewhere in [setUp Thread Group](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/thread-group-jmeter) to get the matching version of ChromeDriver automatically.